ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with HTTP Node server on Docker with WebStorm IDE
I try to setup my WebStorm IDE with Docker in order to run node program thanks to a docker node image. The URL seems to be OK but there is an empty response...
Here is my code. Is there any problem with this?
import {createServer} from 'node:http'

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode(200)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'plain/text')
    res.end('hello world')
}
)

const host='127.0.0.1'
const port=3000
server.listen(port,host,()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on ${host}:${port}`)
})

A http request gives this error:
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000

reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response


EDIT: It works fine with local node.
I have followed this tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/node-with-docker.html#ws_node_docker_test_app
Solution: like suggested below, we can listen on 0.0.0.0. But it seems to be an overkill. So I have launched the image and pickup the true IP address through the json in Docker Desktop in the Inspect tab (Networks).
"Gateway": "Gateway IP",
"GlobalIPv6Address": "",
"GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
"IPAddress": "Container IP",


You need to set host='0.0.0.0'.  If you only listen on 127.0.0.1, the server will be unreachable from outside its own container.
